Flutter, checking notification device settings
I'm using Firebase Messaging to push notification. Everything's fine when i sending notification to device token, but when i wanna check that user have on device notification on or off, ios return me always PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied. On Android everything's great, check correctly. I'm using app_settings and permission_handler to check.
Function to check:
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      if (!await Permission.notification.isGranted) {
        setState(() {
          needNotifications = true;
        });
      }
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      PermissionStatus status = await Permission.notification.request();
      print("Permission Status: $status");

      FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
      NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.getNotificationSettings();

      if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
        setState(() {
          needNotifications = false;
        });
      } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
          AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
        setState(() {
          needNotifications = true;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          needNotifications = true;
        });
      }
      if (status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
        setState(() {
          needNotifications = true;
        });
      }
    }
  }

I added information to Podfile, editing info.plist with :
    <string>Powiadomienia są niezbędne do działania aplikacji</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
    </array>

Tested in simulator ios from xcode, on real device via xcode and by testflight on real device. Always app returns me PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied.

PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied occurs when the user denies permission for the app. You can request the user to grant the required permissions by directing them to the app settings. Refer to the following code snippet:
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future<void> requestPermission() async {
  PermissionStatus status = await Permission.notification.status;

  if (status == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
    // Inform the user to enable permissions from settings
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Permission Required'),
        content: Text(
            'Please enable location permissions in the app settings to proceed.'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: Text('Cancel'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              await openAppSettings(); // Open the app settings
            },
            child: Text('Open Settings'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  } else if (status.isDenied) {
    // Request permission again
    final newStatus = await Permission.location.request();
    if (newStatus.isGranted) {
      print("Permission granted");
    } else {
      print("Permission denied");
    }
  } else if (status.isGranted) {
    print("Permission already granted");
  }
}

Additionally, you also need to add Push Notification in the Signing and Capabilities tab.


I got added this in xcode.
And in my settings also i have everything turned on.
